# How to add check in array based on some conditions around a particular element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have an array named var_name

How to check in an array if there is an element other than detected

but if my array does not contain detected

and contains different element, it shouldn't do anything. For instance:

1. `var_name = [detected, nondetected]` it should execute `<div> Do something </div>`
2. `var_name = [nondetected, inprogress]` it should execute `<div> Do nothing </div>`
3. `var_name = [detected, detected]` it should execute `<div> Do nothing </div>`

Things tried so far:

```
!var_name.includes('detected') ? (<div>Do something</div>) : (<div>Do nothing</div>)
```

but it fails for my usecase

So in order to do something, there needs to be at-most 1 instance of detected followed by other elements (like nondetected, etc). If it contains all detected, then still it doesn't do anything. How to execute such that?

Comment: based on the 3 cases that you have, how about do a for loop to count how many detected are there? or use filter and get the length of the filtered array? if === 1 then do something, else do nothing

Comment: How can I do that? Is there a way to use if-else in return function?

Comment: Do a first pass over the array and reduce it into a count of "detected", then loop it normally to map to JSX and render what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to refine the "matching" functionality, I just use === 'detected' so it's easier to understand.. but this should get you started:

```
const var_name = ['detected', 'detected'];
console.log(var_name.filter((item) => item === 'detected').length);
```

so you can do something like:

```
var_name.filter((item) => item === 'detected').length === 1 ? do something : do nothing
```

Comment: Does ``var_name.filter((item) => item === 'detected').length`` count the number of instances of 'detected' ?

Comment: @SMahajan yes.. but as I said, you might want to refine it

Answer (score 1):

```
const var_name = ["detected", "nondetected", "nondetected", "detected"];
(var_name.filter(x => x == "detected").length === 1) ? console.log("something") : console.log("nothing");
```